# Configuring multi node hadoop install

Tags: linux, hadoop, networking

Im trying to configure a hadoop - master and slave env.

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

So far,
   I have created 2 vagrant(Ubuntu) boxes and installed Hadoop in both the machines and up in running.
   Now, I have assigned a new ipaddress - 192.168.0.1 to my master machine and trying to ssh to that machine but does not work.

ssh localhost - works
   ssh master - does not work

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       vagrant

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

#hadoop
192.168.0.1  master
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow following steps to create passwordless ssh passwordless login.

edit /etc/hosts in all the nodes.
Add master and slave 
192.168.0.1    master
192.168.0.2    slave

`ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@slave
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Now try ssh master and ssh slave

Comment: @Vicky..Im unable to ping my 2 vms

Comment: Then you need to configure your network interface. 
If you using ubuntu it is quite easy. Convert dynamic IP to static IP and modify /etc/hosts you must be able to ping.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the interface with that IP address? Also from which machine you are trying to ssh to that master IP. Where did you build these 2 VMs? on your PC? Post /sbin/ifconfig and netstat -rn output from both master and slave VMs.

Since you mentioned vagrant. This might help https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/index.html